# roscore hangs after ubuntu 14.04.2 upgrade

Tags: roscore, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 14.04.2 through software update manger, when I try and run roscore it it seems to hang in the terminal (i get no terminal output). When i ctl-c to clear I get the following:

```
^C... logging to /home/dambrosio/.ros/log/d1cb7a66-fa64-11e4-a258-000c29e19f77/roslaunch-ubuntu-3242.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
```

When I ctl-c again I get the following:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roscore", line 63, in <module>
    roslaunch.main(['roscore', '--core'] + sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 298, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 260, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 218, in _start_infrastructure
    self._start_server()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 169, in _start_server
    self.server.start()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 376, in start
    code, msg, val = ServerProxy(self.uri).get_pid()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1439, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 562, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I have tried to re-install ros-indigo-desktop-full and python-rosinstall. Any ideas on what is going on, or what changed?
Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209217/roscore-hangs-after-ubuntu-14.04.2-upgrade/) by [dambrosio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19732/dambrosio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2015-05-14

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found that this is usually an issue with the ROS_IP and/or ROS_MASTER_URI being incorrect. Make sure that you have these values correctly set in your environment variables. See link below details on setting these in Ubuntu. See link below:

[ROS/EnvironmentVariables](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables)

---

Originally posted by [dambrosio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19732/dambrosio/) with karma: 161 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2